# URLEncode - getting it to work how I want

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I want to URL encode email addresses.  I input "bmackey@foo.com" on [w3schools,](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) but it did not encode "@" or ".".  I am using `encodeURI()` and have the same results.  What is going on?

At least, I assume it did not encode because I see in FireBug Net tab:

`GET http://dev:8989/SJMUserManager/Service/Index/bmackey@foo.com`

I expected to see

`GET http://dev:8989/SJMUserManager/Service/Index/bmackey%40foo%2Ecom`

Comment: [Please don't patronize w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: The `@` was encoded to `%40` when I tried. The dot was not. You could try encodeURIComponent() to get what you need.

Comment: @Pointy - thanks that info is helpful,  but only slightly applicable to the question.  "I am using encodeURI() and have the same results".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` and `.` are not special characters in HTTP URIs.

The characters that need encoding include space (which becomes `+`), `+` itself, and `%`, which is used to hex-encode.

Other characters outside the normal ASCII range of 32 - 127 and various other characters within that range use that `%` hex encoding.

For correct handling, you should consider using `encodeURIComponent()` but *only* on the part of the URI that was user supplied.  If you encode the entire URI that way you'll get an invalid URI.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `encodeURIComponent` instead.

```
encodeURIComponent('GET http://dev:8989/SJMUserManager/Service/Index/bmackey@foo.com')
```

Return:

```
"GET%20http%3A%2F%2Fdev%3A8989%2FSJMUserManager%2FService%2FIndex%2Fbmackey%40foo.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

@ is a reserved character, and therefore not encoded, you can see the reference at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI